# Error: D:/velilog/bubu.vhd(3): near "clock_in": (vcom-1576) expecting END

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to make a fsm in vhdl using modelsim but when i try and compile my code i have this errors

```
enter code here
entity timer_50Mhz is
    generic(count : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 2);    
        clock_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clock_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end timer_50Mh
z;
architecture Behavioral of timer_50Mhz is
begin
 process(clock_in)
 variable temp :integer range 0 to 5000000 := 0; 
 begin
  if(rising_edge(clock_in)) then 
   if(temp = count-1) then
    temp :=0;
    clock_out <='1';
   else
    temp := temp + 1;
    clock_out <='0';
 end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I would appreciate it if you could solve it.

Comment: Provide [mcve]. It means full code, and testbench.

Comment: just a simple typo this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
entity timer_50Mhz is
    generic(count : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 2);    
        clock_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
        clock_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end timer_50Mhz;
```

should be this:

```
entity timer_50Mhz is
    generic(count : integer range 0 to 50000000 := 2);    
    port(
        clock_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
        clock_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end timer_50Mhz;
```